# how to add search proudect in wordpress by uploading image by code no blugins because they all paid once

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins

how to add search product in WORDPRESS by uploading image by code no plugins because they all paid once what i mean when you look at search bar you see maybe little image icon then the user upload a photo then search with it then respond  with products that looks like the image i just need it to apper on mobile version

did not try anything